# Send Data from Component to another Component

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngx-bootstrap

Goal:
Send data of a variable from app component to SomeComponent. The value of the variable should be displayed inside of the modal body.

Problem:
I don't know how to solve it. Any idea?

Info:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-modal-m9sctv

Thank you!

---

SomeComponent

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left"> {{ title }} </h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    This is a modal.
</div>


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-some',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.css']
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  title;
  constructor(
    public modalRef: BsModalRef
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

---

App component

```
<div class="container my-1">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4>Ngx Bootstrap Modal Component</h4>
      <div (click)="openModal()" class="btn btn-success">Modal Component</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>





import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';

import { SomeComponent } from './some/some.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  private test: string;
  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

  openModal() {

    this.test = "abcdef";

    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(SomeComponent,  {
      initialState: {
        title: 'Modal title',
        data: {}
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have initial state object in your typescript public variable. pass that same object to modal; make changes in your data object properties to pass data.

For eg:-

Stackblitz url :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-modal-mvkgjy

Code :-

HTML :-

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left"> {{ title }} </h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    {{data?.item}}
</div>
```

TS :-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';

import { SomeComponent } from './some/some.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public initialState =  {
        title: 'Modal title',
        data: {}
  };
  private test: string;
  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

  openModal() {

    this.test = "abcdef";

    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(SomeComponent,  {
      initialState: this.initialState,
    });
    this.initialState.data["item"]=123;
    setTimeout(() => this.initialState.data["item"] = 678, 2000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample that you can use stackblitz? It's easier to understand.

Comment: you give me stackblitz of your code. i will modify it.

Comment: 1. Go to this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-modal-m9sctv
2. After compled editing, press the button "Fork" (on top of the screen) and then click OK. 
3. Then you click on the button "Share" and copy the link of editor url.
4. Use the url link to paste it at stackoverflow.

Comment: you are passing intial state, what different do you want?

Comment: For me it doesn't matter. You can remove it if you need. It is not necessary to use it

Comment: Thank you for your help!